# How do I get my new page to show up in the correct menu in Joomla!?

Tags: joomla

I have been asked to edit a website for a client, but the site is built using joomla which I have never used before.

I have built the new page I want, but I cannot get it to show up in the correct menus.  I THINK I just need it to show up in the "Main Menu" part, but I cant figure out how to tell joomla to detect it...

Hating Joomla right now but hoping somone can help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide a website link so we can take a look.

Comment: its Auralia.ie - I'm trying to get a page to appear in one of the menues at the top but for the life of me I can't..

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by "created a page" e.g. do you mean you've created an "article" using `Content->Article Manager->New Article` or a standalone html/PHP file or something else...

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel on the top menu, go to:

```
Menus >> Main Menu (or which ever menu the item belongs to)
```

click on the menu item and on the left hand side under "Parent Item", click "Cosmetic Surgery"

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Regards

Comment: no sorry that's not what I'm looking for at all.. I have created a new page, but I cannot get it to appear in the correct menus.  it will appear in one of the sub menus but I cant find how to tell the program to put the new page in the "Main Menu" section.

Comment: @RyanPress: by "page" do you mean article or menu item?

Comment: @RyanPress: what is the name of the menu item and which menu do you want it to appear under? the navigation bar at the top? If you want to create a temporary admin account and e-mail me the details so I can do it for you, then I would be happy to do that aswell.

Comment: I'm trying to put an item in one of the sub menus in the cosmetic surgery for women menu.

Comment: @RyanPress: please see my updated answer. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I already have it appearing in there, it wont appear on the main menu.  If you put the parent menu as cosmetic surgery you still need to get the item to appear in the main menu list too before it will show up.  right now, with the parent menu as cosmetic surgery, it shows up on the side menu when you go into one of the other "other surgery" options (its the buttocks implants page), however even when you click on it you are not taken to the correct page. I believe this is because it is not linked to the main menu, and this is where I am stuck, how to associate it with the main menu.

Comment: @RyanPress well normally all you need to do is go to "Menus >> Main Menu" and create the link there, but looks like there is something else that going on. As I said before, if you want to e-mail me a temporary admin account, then I will be happy to sort it out for you.

Comment: but how do you "create the link" after you go into the Main Menu part?  This is what I am struggling with.  Sorry I wouldnt be able to create an admin account.

Comment: @RyanPress: you don't "create the link" so to speak. Joomla does all that for you. All you have to do is, 1) give the menu item a name and 2) select the type of menu link. In your case, when you select the type, scroll down till you see the K2 section, then select "item". Sorry if this is still not what you are looking for but your question is terribly confusing. If its showing up in the wrong menu, then create the menu item in the correct menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
See below url:-

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_menu_item_which_points_to_an_Article

Or

http://www.gradientpixels.ca/joomla-tutorials/129-what-are-joomla-hidden-menus
```